# Is matching a poor practice in rails routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is using the following poor practice and does it expose your controller actions to CSRF attacks?

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at `verified_request?` method [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7fb99e5743d88c04357e09960d112376428a6faa/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L93).
It doesn't validate tokens for the `GET` request.

You have to specify HTTP verb in your routes.

```
match "something" => "controller#action", :via => :post
```

Comment: or `post "something" => "controller#action"`

Comment: it doesn't matter, we know nothing about @Simpleton's controllers. :)

Comment: @tiktak, I've noticed, that your comment had +2, and updated my answer